# Replace plasterboard (drywall?) around window

Tags: drywall, windows, plaster

firstly my question is about plasterboard, which I think may be called drywall in the US?

Anyway, during the last few winters it had become damp and is just falling apart. Last summer someone had a quick look for me and it turns out it was caused by a blocked air vent - this has been fixed and there was no dampness last winter and is fine now, so I think it just needs the plasterboard replaced.

As can be seen from the picture, the entire vertical section of the window (question 1 - what is the name for this part of the window?) needs to be replaces plus a small section of the wall.

If I go pulling the old board off, what will I find behind it? How will I fix  the new board on? I can put my fingers through some holes that have formed, near the actual window there is bricks behind (with a small gap) and at the wall side there appears to be nothing.

How would I join up the corners?

Also, if I can't tackle this myself, is this a big job  for a pro? There is a  site where I can get quotes - would  this go in the Plaster or General Builder category?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: It's either plaster (installed not in a sheet, but with a trowel), or it's drywall (sheets of paper-faced gypsum). The two terms are not interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is drywall. I got a guy in to do it in the end, a friend iof a friend, just 100 euro.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize how old this question is.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a space behind the plaster board and the brick wall it is most likely that there have been wooden strips mounted to the brick and then the plaster board has been in turn mounted to those wood strips.

I would expect you to find a strip vertical right next to the window, one on each side of the corner in from the window and then some under the inside wall area. You will learn more simply by proceeding to remove the existing damaged materials. It is possible that some of the stripping was damaged as well and may also require replacement.

As for the installation of the replacement plaster board you would cut pieces of material to fit and then use plaster board screws to mount the pieces to the strips on the wall. The outside corner by the window is normally handled by installing a plasterboard cornice piece (made of metal or plastic) to the corner (with some more screws) and then the plaster board mud is applied at the corner up to this material to produce the finished corner.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a further prod around the area to see if I can find the wood you describe. I'm a bit worried to go tearing down what is there just to explore as it may be too big a job for me. BTW do you know the mane for that part of the window?